# Same stored procedure called multiple times in report

Tags: stored-procedures, ssrs-2008, subreport

I was wondering if anyone knew how to address the slowness I have with one main report that is using 3 subreports, all using the same stored procedure but each only using one sp parameter different than the other 2. The subreports are based off of the same stored procedure, which asks for 6 variables.  Each of the 3 subreports is passing 5 out of 6 of the same parameters as the other ones. Only 1 parameter is different on each of them.

As it stands, the report takes quite some time to run. I believe it's not the most efficient practice to have the same stored procedure firing off multiple times, with just 1 parameter different. It seems redundant. Is there any way to optimize this process?

Comment: what you need is to check the performance of the stored procedure you are calling. Even if you call different stored procedure its not going to change the performance of the report.

Comment: Deep, the way to check the cost is as simple as catching the statements in profiler and checking the reads and execution time. Further more you can check the execution plan as well. About merging i cant comment its entirely up to you and your business team. If they are comfortable then good for you. But again i would advise you to check the performance before and after merging.